# sync_with_stdio (false) on C file I/O?

Tags: c++, c, io

A quick question:
If I optimize C++ code using `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` will it negatively affect my program if I use C file I/O?

I have been checking on many sources, but when they say that it doesn't synchronize with C streams, I don't know if that means that it will affect reading, writing, or creating files using C I/O.

Comment: That function just separates the I/O buffering of the C and C++ libraries.  So it shouldn't affect your C I/O performance.  If you search that function on this site there is much info on how it can affect C++ I/O.

Comment: You have to flush buffers manually in this case otherwise the output may be garbled due to separate buffering for the same stream.